# why does my jquery function not working and view source code without the html return from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

ok i am not sure why is this happen, can someone tell me the answer to this?

this is my code on my html.

i created a link

```
<a id="configPage" href="#">Card List</a>
```

from this link, it will lead to this jquery code when click

```
$("a#configPage").click(function(){
var request = $.get('controller.php',{ action: "configView", subaction: "" });
request.success(function(result) {
  $( "#resultContent" ).html(result);
  console.log(result);
});

request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  if (textStatus == 'timeout')
    console.log('The server is not responding');

  if (textStatus == 'error')
    console.log(errorThrown);

  // Etc
});

return false;
```

});

from the .get, i will go to my php script and return a set of HTML code with forms in it and populate to #resultContent div.

this is working fine. But after my form has been populated in #resultContent div, i have another same link inside that html

```
<a id="configPage" href="#">Card List</a>
```

this time, that link above is not firing the jquery anymore. I found out that the html return is not showing in my view source code. Is this the reason why is not firing? how to solve this? or i am doing it wrong?

edit: everything from the return HTML is not firing any jquery at all such as form on submit button etc. Is like that whole div with the returned html code is not exist

Comment: can replace same element with an identical one but as soon as original is removed so are it's event listeners

Comment: i mean everything that is related to jquery in that return html is not firing at all such as form submit etc.

Comment: read up on how event delegation works as per the link above.

Comment: thanks for the link, i have read up and solved my question. Thanks alot